# Tablet not connected to N wifi

Tags: wi-fi, networking

I have bought a cheap tablet, and it was not able to connect to my N-only wifi. When I set it to NG or G, it connected fine. So I took it back to the shop and had it replaced. The new one has the same problem. I have tried several channels and even disabled the encryption on the router, nothing helped.

The interesting part is, I asked my neighbour to change his network to N-only, and the tablet connected to that one.

Both of us have TP-Link routers, mine with DD-WRT, his with stock rom. 3 other android devices and a Win7 laptop connects to my N-only wifi without problems.

G is fine for browsing, but not enough for streaming.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you configured the N-only network to use only the 5GHz bands? It may be that your device only supports the 2.4GHz bands.

Comment: The router is not capable of 5GHz. Can it happen, that the tablet only knows 5GHz?

Comment: No, since then it wouldn't connect to G-networks either.

Comment: How do I know if a phone knows 5GHz?

Comment: Do you have an XBox?

Comment: No, I have to wired Win7 computers, 3 phones, and 1 tablet. The laptop usually stays at work.